# HTC One V (GSM) Ruu

Tags: boot-loop, htc, stock-rom, htc-one-v

I would like change back the original factory/stock ROM on my HTC One V devices. 
Currently is run an Cyanogenmod 10.1, but the device frozen in boot loop.

**Device data:**
Primo U SHIP S-ON RL
HBOOT-1.18.0000
RADIO-3381.24.00.23_M
eMMC-boot

How can I get back the stock/factory ROM?

Any help?

Thank you for your help!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

[PrimoU](http://androidruu.com/?developer=Primo) RUU

This is about the most complete set of PrimoU RUU's I could find. There is also OTA's as well.

---

Can't answer on the boot looping without further details